# Dismiss UITextField Keyboard With Swipe

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

I am trying to swipe the keyboard down to dismiss it. I am using a UITextField for my keyboard. I have seen similar questions; however, they are using a UIScrollView/ UITextView. The use:

```
scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .Interactive
```

How can I use this for a UITextField? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest solution is to *use* a scroll view. Just put a scroll view behind your entire interface and boom, you're all set. This architecture has too many advantages to be rejected blithely. Even if the scroll view does not scroll normally, the user can use it to scroll when the keyboard is present (so as to be able to see the whole interface). What's more, it scrolls to reveal the first responder *automatically* — plus it gives you the `keyboardDismissMode`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, this doesn't seem to be working. Perhaps it is because I am using a UITableViewController. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: The table view _is_ a scroll view.

Answer (score 1):

UITextField is not a subclass of UIScrollView and it doesn't have any such properties. Anyway, there is a couple solutions, that can help you.

```
1. Dismiss keyboard by tapping Return button:

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
      [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

2. Add an instance of UISwipeGestureRecognizer to your view controller
       and close a

   // keyboard by swipe event:

   @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture;

// set in IB its direction as UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown and connect IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)gestureDidSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if ([self.textField isFirstResponder]) {
        [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

3. Make an UITextField category and add a toolbar with Cancel button above keyboard:

@implementation UITextField (attachCancelItem)

```
- (void)attachDismissToolBar {
    UIToolbar *keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 40.0f)];
    keyboardToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    UIBarButtonItem *spaceBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                                  target:nil
                                                                                  action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString localizedStringFromKey:@"selectAddressElementScreenDoneButtonTitle"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(resignFirstResponder)];

    [keyboardToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spaceBarItem, spaceBarItem, spaceBarItem, item, nil]];
    keyboardToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar;
}
```